# Data transfer between Java code and PLC software to influence the robot

Tags: java, automation, plc, siemens

I am doing an automation project in which I use a Siemens S7 / 1500 PLC and the software is STEP7 using KOP and SCL languages for programming. I also have a separate HMI (industrial PC with Windows installed) with me. I have a mathematical algorithm which I have converted into Java code. The PLC is connected to ABB robot and I want to interface this Java code via PLC to influence the robot arm movements. My question is: What would be better options, can I use same Java code in STEP7 software of Siemens PLC ?? Or is it better to use the Java code directly in the HMI (industrial PC) ??

Comment: You can not use Java for Siemens PLC programming. If you need to execute that algorithm in Java, you need to establish a communication between the Java application and PLC / robot. Can you provide more details about that data exchange? Which type of algorithm is it?

Comment: Hello FrankProp, thank you for your comment. With my system, I am having Profinet as a communication protocol so I will be using that for the data exchange between IPC and PLC.

Comment: If you need a reliable communication between PCs and PLCs, I would suggest you to take a look at OPC UA. It's not the easiest way but it's probably the more flexible and scalable.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a java compiler in STEP7.  Only SCL (IEC611311) for a structured text language.  The exception is if you use a Siemens Open controller which is essentially an industrial pc with a software plc.  Link is [here](https://mall.industry.siemens.com/mall/en/WW/Catalog/Products/10252972)  This actually has a c/c++ compiler available.  That is the close as you will be able to get to java.

So I believe you have 2 options

1. you can rewrite your java code in the native STEP7 SCL language **preferred**
2. you can rewrite your java code to c++ and use the open controller
3. use your other java options

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello @mrsargent! Thank you for your comment. Also, can I use a Raspberry Pi? Let´s say I use an IDE to connect my RPi to my computer, write the Java code in that IDE, and somehow connect the RPi over Profinet to my Siemens PLC ? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes I suppose that's possible.  But I see a few things you need to be aware of. 1) the speed at which the Raspberry PI runs your java code 2) the speed of the communication transfer over profinet 3) the development of the profinet driver to have the plc communicate the the rasberry pi.